# Why is Xcode prompting for this method?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm adding some new code to an existing app and started to create the new method --

```
- (void)removeAnnotationCurtain
```

As soon as I typed "remove" the Xcode editor prompted me for a bunch of `remove` methods, including `removeAnnotationCurtain:(NSSet*)` and `removeAnnotationCurtainAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)`.  Also in the list were similarly named methods for (apparently) all the other properties defined in the class.  (And, no, they're not defined anywhere in the project.)

I'll admit I don't keep up with all the latest stuff, but I've never heard of these methods before.  Are they some sort of KVC thing?

(To those who like to jump on the `xcode` tag, I figure its use *is* warranted because I'm seeing this symptom while editing in Xcode.)

Comment: It's just autocomplete making guesses. If the methods aren't in your app, then they are probably in the SDK (search the SDK documentation for them) or in a third party framework that you have included (see their documentation).

Comment: Like I said, there are methods for every property in the class.  I don't think that there's a method named "caliperStoreNameTextBoxAtIndexes" in the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a KVC thing. These are [KVC To-Many methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html). I assume you have a property called `annotationCurtain`? You'll get similar behavior if you start a `-(void)insert...` or `-(void)add...`.

Xcode doesn't seem to care what the type of the property is, though. It's not quite that smart yet.